# Хранение учетных записей пользователей в SQL таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется MSSQL сервер, БД и таблица Users, в которой я храню пользователей вместе с хэш пароля. Создал процедуру создания пользователей где вставляю данные в Users, при этом имеется триггер на insert где хочу записывать инфу в другую таблицу. Вопросы возникли следующие:

1. Нормальная ли это практика, хранить инфу о пользователе в таблице, не создавая логин и пользователя БД через конструкции Create Login.., Create User..)? Ведь сейчас запросы к БД выполняются от созданного вручную системного пользователя (для проверки соединения к БД, получения какой-либо информации на сайте).
2. Как тогда получить информацию в триггере о том, кто в данный момент пытается вставить данные в Users, например. Потому как предопределенная переменная inserted в триггере содержит инфу только согласно полям таблицы, в которую происходит вставка. Надеюсь понятно описал суть, кто может подскажите, потому как появляются ощущения что делаю что-то не правильно.

Comment: @Akina, в моем случае пользователи хранятся в таблице Users и все. Выше перечисленные функции я так понимаю работают только с данными, хранимыми в СУБД при использовании конструкции CREATE LOGIN, CREATE USER.. Или я вас неправильно понял.

Comment: @Akina, неправильно выразился. Логин и хэш пароля для входа на сайт хранятся в таблице, логин sql и пользователь бд не создавался.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте разберём пользователей.

1. Пользователи Базы данных. (user/pass для доступа к БД)
2. Пользователи приложения. (user/pass для доступа к приложению)
3. Прочие пользователи. (user/pass для доступа к приложению, но только это другие сервисы)
4. Пользователи системы (2 + 3)

Я так понимаю вам нужно знать какой пользователь системы создал что.
для этого держим Поля в каждой нужной вам таблице `CreateBy,` `CreatedOn, ModefiedBy, ModefiedOn ...` Хранить информацию о пользователе который ввел данные это нормально.   Передавать в процедуре эти данные о пользователе который создаёт запись. `procedure CreateUser(loginId, ...userdata)`. Зачем это делать в триггере не понятно конечно?

Если создается новый логин для доступа к приложениям то нужно указать кто из залогинившихся пользователей делает это действие. Понятно что в системе существует `Admin` которфй был заложен системой.

Comment: В триггере удобно проверять на ошибки все моменты при вставке данных, и как вариант записывать историю. Если поля делать подобно "CreateBy" в триггере конечно их получу, но думал есть какой-то другой вариант, более эстетичный чтоле..

Comment: @haswell Конечно триггеры вешь которая есть давно. Но это то что деляется неявно в вашего ведома или нет если это не ваш триггер. Работать с триггерами неудобно потому что нужно постоянно следить за тем когда он вызовится а когда нет.

Comment: @haswell писать логгеры вы всё равно будите. Так лучше явно вызвать его нежели кто-то его вставит неявно

Comment: Возможно вы правы, я бы хотел их использовать только для ведения истории, т.е. записи в другую таблицу информации о том, кто-что сделал